# Laravel how download file for Auth() user in dashboard view

Tags: php, laravel, download, laravel-blade, file-storage

I have big problem to enable Auth users download stored files in laravale storage. Users has in table `users` field `id_message` which is unique name of folder where user has file to download.

What has to be made in `AuthController` which controll `dashboard.blade` to access user download file ? problem is how add from table variable `id_message` to `file path`

File is stored `/app/files/{id_message}/*.zip`

```
return response()->download(store_path('app/files/'.(Auth()->user()->id_message).'/*.zip'));
```

And at the end, what will be in blade

```
<td><a href="{{ }}">Download</a></td>
```

Can't understand why is this problem so hard to solve it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use an `<a>` tag with file url as the `href` of the tag.

```
<a href="{{ storage_path('app/files/'.auth()->user()->id_message.'/file.zip') }}" title="Download" target="_blank">
    Download
</a>
```

or you can do it with a controller method.

route

```
Route::get('download-my-file', 'MyController@downloadZipFile')->name('downloadZipFile');
```

controller

```
public function downloadZipFile()
{
   $fileName = storage_path('app/files/'.auth()->user()->id_message.'/file.zip');
   return response()->download($fileName);
   // you can add file name as the second parameter
   return response()->download($fileName, 'MyZip.zip');
   // you can pass an array of HTTP headers as the third argument
   return response()->download($fileName, 'MyZip.zip', ['Content-Type: application/octet-stream', 'Content-Length: '. filesize($fileName))]);

   // you can check for file existence. 
   if (file_exists($fileName)) {
       return response()->download($fileName, 'MyZip.zip');
   } else {
       return 0;
   }
}
```

and in view

```
<a href="{{ route('downloadZipFile') }}" target="_blank">
    Download
</a>
```

Comment: The "view" examples could be more helpful. A `button` -- or any interactive content --cannot be nested within an `a` element. It's invalid html.

[4.5.1 The a element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)

Answer (score 1):

To create a download link,(See [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#file-downloads))

```
$filepath = app_path() . '/files/' . Auth::user()->id_message . '/*.zip'
if(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::exists($filepath)){
    return response()->download($filepath, 'your_filename', [
        'Content-Length: '. filesize($filepath)
    ]);    
}else{
    return false; //you can show error if it returns false
}
```

In blade, just call the url (get method),

```
<td><a href="{{ url('download/' . auth->user()->id_message) }}" 
 target="_blank">Download</a></td>
```